# How to call iOS Objective C method from Javascript (Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

### Crux

Calling a method defined in Objective C from a JS file. Phonegap framework is being used.

### Objective C method

MyClassViewController.h file contains

```
-(int) returnTen;
```

MyClassViewController.m file contains

```
-(int) returnTen
{
     return 10;
}
```

### What I want to do?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        var num = //Invoke "returnTen" so that 10 is stored in num variable
        pText.innerHTML = num;
    }

 </script>
 </head>
 </html>
```

Comment: Check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049500/how-to-call-ios-method-from-java-script-using-phonegap/12049704#12049704

Comment: Thanks Arjun, but I've already wrote a blog post about how to do it in a better way. Sadly the blog post is now deleted.