# how to call ios method from java script using phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am new with phonegap in IOS.
I make the project as per guide line of phone gap.
But now i want to go one step forward. 
how can i call a method of AppDelegate or any other IOS Class?

Can any body Suggest Me?

Here is my Code:

```
<p> 
         <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
                                    <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Password" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="login button"> 
                                    <input onfocus="alert('focus on')" type="button" value="Login" onclick="login();"/> 
                                </p>
```

My Script Function:

```
function login(){
    // here I want call any appDelegate Method   
}
```

I feel nice if some guy help me to reach my point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hi  ithink this may help you
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide